# PATINDEX() replacement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

i am converting a sql server script where i need to convert PATINDEX() in MYSQL. would you please suggest which MYSQL function is similar to PATINDEX()

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: http://www.owalog.com/blog.php?myess1=57

Comment: thanks for the feedback. but will this LOCATE() work like PATINDEX? what about REGXP

Comment: REGEXP simply returns 1 if string matches pattern or 0 if it doesn't:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 2):

[REGEXP_INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) is close in functionality to PatIndex, but you will need to be running MySQL 8.0 or later to use it.

8.0 was released April 2018.  Confusingly, the last version released before 8.0 was 5.7.  Wikipedia [explains why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

While there is no formal `PATINDEX()` function in MySQL that achieves both the regex pattern lookup with returned character index, or a combination of `LOCATE()` and `REGEXP()`, consider a User-Defined function that loops through each character in the length of a string and checks a `REGEXP` pattern on the character. Once created, use such a function in-line of a query.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PatIndex;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION PatIndex(pattern VARCHAR(255), tblString VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INTEGER
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    SET i = 1;

    myloop: WHILE (i <= LENGTH(tblString)) DO

        IF SUBSTRING(tblString, i, 1) REGEXP pattern THEN
            RETURN(i);
            LEAVE myloop;        
        END IF;    

        SET i = i + 1;

    END WHILE; 

    RETURN(0);

END
```

Query *(searches for first digit in string)*

```
SELECT mystring, PatIndex('[0-9]', mystring) As FirstNumberCharacter
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution :D

```
ORDER BY
CASE
WHEN instr([column], '[text]') > 0 THEN
  instr([column], '[text]')
WHEN instr([column], '[text]') = 0 THEN
  100(//large number) end ASC
```