# MySQL Select only part of column

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

How can i select only a part of a column ? I know I can use substring, but i need to select a string part of a column. As an example: Column can contain the following:

`DIRL100`

I need to select only the `DIRL` part in one column, and the `100` part as another.

I *could* do it with this specific column like so:

`SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 5) AS part1,
SUBSTRING(column, 1, 4) AS part2 ....`

But i cannot be sure that its always 4 letters (DIRL) before it gets numeric .. Can i somehow use REGEXP or something to extract only the numeric part and the letter part in each column ?

In other words.. Can i split a column by where the letters end. It could as an example contain `DIRL100` or `AB100200` which should be split into two columns each containing the letters from the column (DIRL or AB) and the digits from the column (100 or 100200) ?

Comment: totally don't understand your problem, could you please give some example and expected output ?

Comment: (But i cannot be sure that its always 4 characters (DIRL) before it gets numeric) Then what is your split condition?

Comment: Split condition is when prefix ends which is letters. Will update question

Comment: You need MariaDB's `regexp_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this request:

```
SELECT LEFT(column, patindex('%[0-9]%', column)-1) AS Part1
     , RIGHT(column, LEN(column) - patindex('%[0-9]%', column)+1) AS Part2
```

Comment: That's sql server, the question is about mysql. patindex can be created for mysql though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315658/patindex-replacement-in-mysql

Comment: Ooops... MySQL missed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the regexp functions in MySQL is limited. You have to write a custom function to help you.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_index;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_index(targetString VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    DECLARE min_index INTEGER;
    DECLARE current_index INTEGER;
    SET i = 0;
    SET min_index = NULL;

    loopNumbers: WHILE (i <= 9) DO
        SET current_index = LOCATE(i, targetString);
        IF current_index > 0 THEN
            IF min_index IS NULL OR current_index < min_index THEN
              SET min_index = current_index;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        SET i = i + 1;

    END WHILE; 

    RETURN(min_index);

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What this function does is to obtain the first position of the numbers. Then using this function, you can modify your query to:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 1 FOR get_index(column_name)-1) AS first, SUBSTRING(column_name FROM get_index(column_name)) AS second 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[a-Z]+[0-9]+$'
```

The additional WHERE condition is optional to ensure that only data in the correct format is selected.