# Split values and loop through them

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I have two tables:
Table1:

```
id | value
1  | val1
2  | val2
3  | val3
```

Table2:

```
id | value
1  | val1,val2,val22
2  | val2
3  | val3,val15,
```

The thing that I want to do is to split the values from Table2 by comma (to get separated values), next loop through it and find them in Table1. As a result I need the Table1.id and Table2.id that contains value from Table1 to insert them in the new table.

Is it possible to do it in mysql as there is no SPLIT function?

Edit: MySql version 5.7.27

Edit2: Desired result:

```
table1.id  table1.valie  table1.id  table1.valie
        1          val1          1  val1,val2,val22
        2          val2          1  val1,val2,val22
        2          val2          2  val2
        3          val3          3  val3,val15,
```

Comment: *As a result I need* Show it as a table. And specify your MySQL version.

Comment: *Edit: MySql version 5.7.27* What is maximal amount of commas in `table2.value`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to put it in the question. Edited.

Comment: @Akina it can be zero, it can be 5, but I think not more than 10.

Comment: "I think" is not a criteria... what is `table2.value` datatype, precisely?

Comment: It's varchar(4095)

Comment: So in theory it may consist from 4094 commas and one 1-char value somewhere in the middle... and this value must be extracted. Due to your version this means that you must generate a pseudo-table with the numbers from 1 to 4094 at least in a subquery.

Comment: I'd recommend to create stored procedure instead of a single query - it will be more simple.

Comment: PS. And i'd like to see the desired result for shown source data - format it as a table, like source, and specify, does it must be a content of some source table, some another table, or simple output recordset.

Comment: @Akina Yeah I know that creating a procedure will be the best option. At the end when I will have those ids, I'd like to do Insert them to another table. Like this: INSERT INTO match (id_table1,  d_table2, `comment`, `active`, `date_add`, `date_upd`) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table3
SELECT t1.id `t1.id`, t1.value `t1.value`, t2.id `t2.id`, t2.value `t2.value`
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.value, t2.value);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=603c409cd4ca11d25b25f0eb9c4a83b1)

Answer (score 1):

> MySql version 5.7.27

Use (assuming that `table2.value` contains not more than 10 separate values)

```
CREATE TABLE table3
/* or INSERT INTO table3 (value) if this table already exists */
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT value
       FROM table1 
     UNION
       SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.value, ',', numbers.num), ',', -1)) value
       FROM table2,
            ( SELECT 1 num UNION 
              SELECT 2 UNION 
              SELECT 3 UNION 
              SELECT 4 UNION 
              SELECT 5 UNION 
              SELECT 6 UNION
              SELECT 7 UNION
              SELECT 8 UNION
              SELECT 9 UNION
              SELECT 10 ) numbers
       WHERE numbers.num <= LENGTH(table2.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(table2.value, ',', '')) + 1
       HAVING value != '') total;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a92259573318fa7bba1b6b2057afa133)

Comment: This one select just the values, I'd like to SELECT table1.id, table1.value, table2.id, table2.value to compare it.

Comment: @demoo I have asked you - SHOW THE RESULT. As a table. You're lazy - and I'm not smart.

Comment: *I'd like to SELECT table1.id, table1.value, table2.id, table2.value to compare it.* **against** *I'd like to do Insert them to another table. Like this: INSERT INTO match (id_table1, d_table2, comment, active, date_add, date_upd) ...* - please decide what you want in practice. Select ONE variant.

Comment: Yeah, but I said _INSERT INTO match (id_table1, d_table2, comment, active, date_add, date_upd)_ so by this I understand that still I need those ids from both tables. Btw thanks! I thought without procedure it's impossible to do that.

Comment: @demoo Possible. Moreover, I think it is easy enough.

Comment: It doesnt work as it should https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3233375220330daec2a1e8b529756f8. It returns some mix of columns. Its not matching of two of those tables.

Comment: @demoo Each record in final table is distinct. Two records with the same `id` have different `value`, and backward. What is wrong? PS. Does the desired result is so extreme secret?

Comment: I edited the first post and put there the result that I'd like to see.

Comment: @demoo If you did it right away, we would save a lot of time and nerves. The task occures to be absolutely different. I'll create second answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help you.

[PATINDEX() replacement in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315658/patindex-replacement-in-mysql)

After getting index split rows by index values.Your data will become like below

```
Table2:
id | value
1  | val1
1  | val2
1  | valu22
2  | val2
3  | val3
3  | val15
```

then you can do something like :

```
select * from table2 where value in (select value from table1)
```

Comment: This does not allow to obtain a lot of destination records from one source record.