# Searching database for addresses with certain outcodes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find addresses from a MySQL database by outcode, ie the first letters of a UK postcode. The following snippet works fine for two letter outcodes:

```
select * from addresstable where LEFT (Postcode, 2) in ('CB','PE','IP')
```

but I need it to work in cases where the outcode may be only one letter, ie:

```
select * from addresstable where LEFT (Postcode, 2) in ('B','BS','GL')
```

and the Left statement will of course fail on the single letter case.

How best can I do this search?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on UK postcodes, but it seems they always start with either one letter or two, followed by at least one digit. If that is true, you could use PATINDEX to find the first number, and then use SUBSTRING to get the first characters up to that first number:

```
select *
from addresstable
where SUBSTRING(Postcode,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Postcode)-1) in ('B','BX','GL')
```

Apparently, PATINDEX isn't built-in with MySQL. There are some functions you can create that simulates the behavior if you want to go that route. Another option, but a bit more clunky, but may work is to just check the second character to see if it is numeric or not. If it is, use the LEFT for one character, otherwise use the LEFT for two characters:

```
select *
from @addresstable
where (case when concat('',SUBSTRING(Postcode,2,1) * 1) = SUBSTRING(Postcode,2,1) then left(Postcode,1) else left(Postcode,2) end) in ('B','BX','GL')
```

Comment: This approach looks ideal to me, I failed to mention that the list of outcodes is generated by the PHP script and so varies.  scaisEdge's OR solution would work but needs more code to create the SQL statement.  However, when I tried using your example, I get a PATINDEX function not found error, so I need to look into that.

Comment: @tesan-man Yeah, sorry about that. PATINDEX may not been built-in with MySQL. Maybe this will help: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315658/patindex-replacement-in-mysql)

Comment: @tesan-man Edited my answer to include a possible MySQL alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR clause for length 1

```
select * 
from addresstable 
where LEFT(Postcode, 2) in ('BS','GL')
OR  LEFT(Postcode, 1) =  'B'
```

or

```
select * 
from addresstable 
where LEFT(Postcode, 2) = 'GL'
OR  LEFT(Postcode, 1) =  'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.  To get postcodes that start with "B", "BS", or "GL":

```
where Postcode regexp '^(B|BS|GL)'
```

Of course, this example is a bit silly because postcodes that start with BS also start with B, so this can be simplified to:

```
where Postcode regexp '^(B|GL)'
```